# How to pass list of images as MLMultiArray in coreML Swift?

Tags: swift, swiftui, coreml

I have a image classification model, whose input is:

```
MultiArray (Float32 1 × 224 × 224 × 3)
```

and output:

```
MultiArray (Float32)
```

And I am not able to figure out how to pass the input in the `prediction` function.
I have a list of images, which i got through this code

```
let fileList = FileManager.default.enumerator(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys: keys)
let ar = try? MLMultiArray(shape: [1, 224, 224, 3], dataType: MLMultiArrayDataType.float32)
let model = try Classification(configuration: MLModelConfiguration())
for case let file as URL in fileList {
    guard url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() else {
        continue
    }
    let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: file.path)!
    
    // ar?[i] = getArrayOfBytesFromImage(imageData: image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)! as NSData)
    url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
}
```

How can I pass list of images into MLMultiArray?

Comment: Have you ability export model with addition parameters in coremltools, for example:
image_input = ct.converters.mil.input_types.ImageType(name='input_image', shape=(1, 3, 224, 224), scale=1.0, bias=None, color_layout='RGB', channel_first=None)
mlmodel_image = ct.convert(mlmodel, inputs=[image_input])

Then you will have ability use CVPixelBuffer, it's much clear and easy.